# How to get image size (height & width) and check image using JavaScript on IE?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge

Are there any JavaScript or jQuery APIs or methods to get the dimensions of an image on the page?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30Hhl.jpg)

Comment: Welcome. Please see [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

```
$("#file").change(function (event) {
    var file = this.files[0];
    if (file) {
        var imagefile = file.type;
        var match = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/jpg", "image/tiff"];
        if (!((imagefile == match[0]) || (imagefile == match[1]) || (imagefile ==
            match[2]))) {
            $('#portal_introduce_file').val("");
            this.files = null;
            alert("有効な画像ファイルを選択してください。\n注：許可される画像タイプは jpeg、png、jpg、tiff、pngのみです。")
            return false;
        } else {
            // 画像の寸法を取得するヘルパー
            img = new Image();
            img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
            // 次のハンドラーは、画像が正常に読み込まれた後に起動します
            img.onload = function () {
                debugger
                if (img.width <= 750 && img.height <= 170) {
                    $('#portal_introduce_file').val(file.name);
                }
                else {
                    alert('「' + img.width + 'x' + img.height + '」' + 'サイズが無効です。\n' + '画像: 750x170ビクセルで作成');
                    $('#portal_introduce_file').val("");
                }
            };
            img.onerror = function () {
                alert('画像に問題がありました。')
                $('#portal_introduce_file').val("");
            };
        }
    }
});
```